# How do I trigger this function to be called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('input[name="CBWaive"]').click(function () {
         console.log("Entering");
}
```

I am trying to call this function programmatically?

My attempt

```
$("#CBWaive").on("change", checkBoxClick);
checkBoxClick();
$("#CBWaive").attr("checked", "checked");

function checkBoxClick() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("Is checked!");
    }
}
```

When I click the checkbox with ID CBWaive, I get the console.log

when I try to enter this programmatically, (with code above) nothing happens. No Console Log.

Comment: That all looks fine. What's the problem? It's hard to help not knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: The function uses `this` -- what should that be when you call it outside an event handler?

Answer (score 1):

`checkBoxClick()` needs to be called from an event handler, because it uses `$(this)` to test the element that was clicked.

If you want to trigger it programmatically, call the `change()` method on the element.

```js
$("#CBWaive").on("change", checkBoxClick);
$("#CBWaive").attr("checked", "checked").change();

function checkBoxClick() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("Is checked!");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="CBWaive" name="CBWaive">
```

Comment: This did not trigger the $('input[name="CBWaive"]').click(function () event handler

Comment: Does the element have `id="CBWaive"`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure "this" refers to the checkbox element when you call the checkBoxClick function. You can achieve this by using the [JS call method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which takes as first parameter what "this" should be in the called function.

```
checkBoxClick.call($("#CBWaive"));
```

Comment: `this` is the DOM element, not the jQuery object. That's why you need to write `$(this)` to wrap it in jQuery.

Comment: You are right, my jQuery is a bit rusty. I think jQuery detects that the DOM element is already wrapped and won't wrap it again, so the code still works.
The cleanest would be: checkBoxClick.call(document.getElementById("CBWaive"));

Comment: Actually, it unwraps it and wraps it again, but you're right that it will still work.

Comment: But sometimes jQuery event handlers access `this` directly as a DOM element, e.g. `console.log(this.id);`, which wouldn't work the way you called it.